# scala - How to separate public API from implementation while providing a default one

Tags: scala, design-patterns

I would like to develop a framework in which users may inject their own code inside our platform, without knowing some of our implementation details that may change in near future (e.g Database type).

I have splitted the code into two distinct projects:

- One containing public APIs
- One containing the server-side implementation

However, I would like they can test their code, with a kind of default implementation of some of this API.

For instance, in the **public API**:

```
trait UserDatabase {
  def getAllUserInfo : List[UserInfo]
  ...
}

trait ExecutesOnServer{
  def doWhaterverYouWant(db <: UserDatabase ) : Unit
}
```

In the **user code**:

```
class ExecutesOnServerImpl{
  @override def doWhaterverYouWant(db <: UserDatabase) : Unit {
    db.getAllUserInfo.foreach(println)
  }
}
```

Now in the **private implementation**:

```
class MySQLUserDatabase extends UserDatabase {
  @override def getAllUserInfo : List[UserInfo] = mysql.query(...)
  ...
}
```

I would like the user to have access a kind of default impl like `LocalTextFileUserDatabase` to test their code, and this is replaced my the server side one on the server.

What is the best way to do this ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Dependency injection? like [guice](https://github.com/google/guice) or [macwire](https://github.com/adamw/macwire)

Comment: @Odomontois Thanks for your help, I would like to avoid as possible third-party libraries. I do not know if any design pattern could solve this.

Comment: @ogen yes, with Scala you can do DI without any third-party libs by implementing the [cake pattern](http://jonasboner.com/real-world-scala-dependency-injection-di/)

Answer (score 0):

You can inject different concrete implementations depending on the current environment. For example, `if SERVER_ENV == "local"` you'll create an instance of `LocalTextFileUserDatabase` otherwise `MySQLUserDatabase`.